# Prove that $(2)$ is a prime ideal in $\mathbb Z[w]$

Tags: ring-theory, ideals, principal-ideal-domains

Let $w\in\mathbb C$ be such that $w^3=1$ and $w\neq1$. Prove that $(2)$ is a prime ideal in $\mathbb Z[w]$, and describe $\mathbb Z[w]/(2)$.

What I wanted to do is to show that $\mathbb Z[w]$ is a PID, then $(2)$ would be prime because it's principal. To show that, I thought it would be easier to show a stronger claim that $\mathbb Z[w]$ is an Euclidean domain, but wasn't able to.

My textbook doesn't do a terrific job of explaining the notation here so I'm half-guessing that $\mathbb Z[w]=\{a+bw+cw^2:a,b,c\in\mathbb Z\}$.

Then I tried to construct a Euclidean function. Since $(a+bi)\mapsto(a^2+b^2)$ works for $\mathbb Z[i]$, I tried the similar $(a+bw+cw^2)\mapsto(a^2+b^2+c^2)$, but didn't know how to prove any of the properties for it.

Comment: Hints: Note that since $1 + w + w^{2} =0,$ we have $\mathbb{Z}[w] = \{ a+bw : a,b \in \mathbb{Z} \}.$ Try multiplying $a +bw$ by its complex conjugate for the Euclidean function.

Comment: While some of your ideas are good the assertion that the ideal would be prime because it is principal is false in general. You'd need to show in addition that you cannot factor $2$ in a nontrivial way. To this end use the euclidean function.

Comment: @GeoffRobinson What, what? Why is that equal to zero? I feel like I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: Note that $x^{3} - 1 = (x-1)(x^{2}+x+1)$ and consider what this says when $x = w.$

Comment: The minimal polynomial of $w$ is $x^2-x+1$, so that $\mathbf Z[w]=\{a+bw\mid a,b\\mathbf Z\}$. The euclidean function in this case is $a^2-ab+b^2$. It is indeed a euclidean ring, but you can have up to 4 quotients.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The ring $\mathbf Z[w]$ is isomorphic to the quotient ring $A=\mathbf Z[x]/(x^2+x+1)$. To show $2$ is prime, you have to show $A/2A$ is an integral domain.

We have:
$$A/2A \simeq \mathbf Z[x]/(2,x^2+x+1)\simeq \mathbf Z/2\mathbf Z[x]/(x^2+x+1)$$
so it is enough to show the polynomial $x^2+x+1$ is irreducible over $\mathbf Z/2\mathbf Z$, which means it has no root. It is easy to see the associated polynomial function is the constant $1$.

Comment: The 3rd cyclotomic polynomial is actually $x^2 + x + 1$, so I think that's the polynomial you wanted in the first place.

Comment: You're right. Sorry for the typo

Comment: In fact your quotient is a field (it is $\Bbb F_4$), whence the ideal is actually maximal.

Comment: It's true. It's a field as is the case for the quotient of any polynomial ring over any field by an irreducible polynomial. I just wanted to give as simple an answer as possible.